# SQL - Summing hours in a table grouped by work type

Tags: sql, select, sum

Using a database, I have a table with 2 columns: amount of hours worked, and type of work.  I want to sum the number of hours for each work type.
For example, my "work" table has 2 columns:

```
+---------+------------+
|  hours  |  type      |
+---------+------------+
|  5      |  ABC       |
|  7      |  DEF       |
|  3      |  GHJ       |
|  9      |  ABC       |
+---------+------------+
```

And I need it to return 14 hours for type ABC

I need to use it in a select statement as part of other columns I am pulling.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is very basic for sql query

Comment: Trivial SQL usage covered in the most basic documentation

Answer (score 3):

```
Select type, sum(hours) total_hours from work group by type
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT SUM(hours), type FROM work GROUP BY type
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select type, sum(hours) as "amount of hours worked" from work group by type
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `group by` to achieve your result

```
Select type, sum(hours) total_hours from work group by type
```

`group by` class is used to find the sum based on the columns specified after the group by class. You can specify more than one column after the group by.

For more detail: [Group By](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-group-by.htm)